# how can i see the BPF in quote entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, microsoft-dynamics

I have an issue with my business process flow from Opportunity to Quote:

we have a Custom BPF it look like this:
[image]

the Problem is when i add my quote from the Subgrid i can not see the BPF More :

[image]

**i want know if there is any way to show the BPF in the quote record too ?**

Comment: I see on your quote entity, you have more than 1 forms. Is your BPF enabled for all the forms or the form you are showing in screenshot?

Comment: Hallo @AnkUser i just used for this Form !

Comment: And it is active for this form? Also when you create record directly from quote entity do you see your bpf?

Comment: @AnkUser no it started with the opportunity entity so if i go direct to create quote i can't see it .

Comment: Then I belive it is not enabled for quote entity and for a from you refer.